# How do I track down a Deprecation that occurs "likely near" a point?

Tags: julia

When my code (or perhaps a library it is using, employs a deprecated function,
I get a warning about it (which is good)

Often it doesn't tell me where it occurs but instead says something like

> WARNING: Base.ASCIIString is deprecated, use String instead.
>     likely near /mnt_/.../foobar.jl:2

But I look in `foobar.jl`
and nowhere are any `Base.ASCIIString`'s used.

So presumably they are being used by some of the modules I am `using`, or `import`ing from.

**Why is a line number, for a line in those modules, not given?**

(I am hoping knowing why, can help me work out which module, or module used by that module etc. Had the deprecation)